# Advice needed: How to correctly handle self-signed ssl cert+key pairs for encrypting inter-container communication?

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, containers

Probably some rather noob questions but I have searched around but haven't been able to figure out the best way to handle self-signed certs (from an opsec perspective) to encrypt communication between dockerized services on my Debian server like Redis, Authelia, Portainer, etc.?

The certificates are created and signed and all the containers in question are prepared for host-mounting volumes for cert-key pairs.

So the question is simply:

1. Do I just store the cert-key pairs in the folders already mounted to the containers like e.g. `/docker/appdata/portainer/config`?
2. Who should be the owner:group of the certs+keys pairs, root or the user running the container or something third?
3. Which permissions should be set for the certs+key pairs?

By the way. My docker is setup as a single-node swarm and all containers deployed with stack deploy and properly connected to one another with custom docker bridge networks and communication is working so my question is only related to the handling of the cert+key pairs

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I just store the cert-key pairs in the folders already mounted to the containers like e.g. /docker/appdata/portainer/config?

I would recommend using [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/).  You have the option of creating secrets with [`docker secret create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret_create/) or loading them in from files on the host.  e.g.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu
    secrets:
      - source: my-cert
        target: /certs/my-cert.crt # Load it into /certs/my-cert.crt, default is /run/secrets/{secret_name}
        mode: 0400                 # Read only by owner, default is 444
        # uid: '0'                 # Default UID is root, change if needed.
        # gid: '0'                 # Default GID is root, change if needed.
      - source: my-other-cert
        target: /certs/my-other-cert.crt
        mode: 0400
secrets:
  my-cert:
    external: true                 # Load cert from a secret made with "docker secret create"
  my-other-cert:
    file: ./some-cert.crt          # Load cert from a file on your host machine
```

> Who should be the owner:group of the certs+keys pairs, root or the user running the container or something third?

Almost certainly root, unless it's another user running inside the container.  You can configure this via the `uid` and `gid` options on secrets.

> Which permissions should be set for the certs+key pairs?

You want `400` or `444` on everything generally.  Using secrets has the added benefit of making these files un-writeable from the container (even to root).  You can configure this with the `mode` option on secrets.

If you are going to load a secret from a file on disk instead of using `docker secret create`, it should be from shared storage that's accessible on all swarm nodes.  I know you said it's a swarm of one, just added for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kthompso. This is the first time I ever see the long syntax used  for secrets. In the example above, it seems like with long syntax, you are able to specify where in the container, the secret should be "placed" rather than it just being placed in the /run/secrets directory, correct?

Comment: @problemshavearisen yes exactly, from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/):   "secrets allow you to specify a custom location using the target option."

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try.